# Another directio... I mean directors puzzle (2012)

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

A letter has been replaced with an X. Given the four directors below, replace the question mark with the correct director.

[image]

Hint 1

> Movies with... *(hint in title).*

Comment: FWIW, I had (hopefully) the correct idea before that hint, but I couldn't find relevant information from the director on the right side.

Comment: @ACB Haha. No wonder you couldn't find any helpful information, wrong person, start with the same names! Fixed now.

Comment: @ACB You weren't the only one. I don't believe the person in the original image ever truly 'directed' anything...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Here goes my attempt.*

We can find the directors in the picture and some of their movies as follows:

> Dick Mass- [Down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Down_(film)) (2001)
>  Stan-Lee Ray Baker- [Left](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3518954/) (2017)
>  Pete Docter- [Up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_(2009_film)) (2009)
>  Paco Cabezas- [Mr. Right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Right_(2015_film)) (2015)

Note that these movies are the names of directions as hinted by the title.

Now we see that,

> these directions are not placed correctly.
>
> ```
>      Down
> Right    Left
>       Up
> ```
>
> They are flipped horizontally and vertically.

So we move to the image on right side

> and flip it accordingly.
>
>  [image: image1]

What physical object does this inversion?

Well, yes, it's a

> mirror.

Now we see that the letter `X` can be replaced with

> `R` to get that familiar word.

> MIRROR MIRROR!

So the question mark should possibly be replaced by

> [image: image2]
>  **Tarsem Singh**, who directed the movie [Mirror Mirror](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror_Mirror_(film)) (2012).

<sup>*I couldn't make sense of the red lines on the images.</sup>

**PS:** As the OP explains,

> images should be reflected in the given direction, into the empty middle rectangle, whereafter the red lines are ordered from top to bottom. That gives the arrangement of the red strings on the right side.

Comment: I would accept this as an answer even if it wasn't! +1

Comment: Well done! This is indeed the inteneded answer. The idea was that the images should be rot13(ersyrpgrq, va gur tvira qverpgvba, vagb gur rzcgl erpgnatyr naq pbvapvqr. Tvivat 4 ebjf. Guvf znxrf gur "qbja yvar" gbc yvar, "evtug yvar" frpbaq yvar, "hc yvar" guveq yvar naq "yrsg yvar" sbhegu yvar. Neenatr gur erq yrggref ba gur evtug nppbeqvatyl naq lbh trg gur nafjre.)

Comment: @Prim3numbah , that makes sense. I've edited in that info.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to give this a try, and I apologize because I know it could be far off lol.

> After the new update by the OP, looks like the images are of the people related to movies with the titles having name of a direction in it.

So, we have -

> DICK MAAS([DOWN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Down_(film)))
>  PACO CABEZAS ([Mr. RIGHT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Right_(2015_film)))
>  STAN-LEE RAY BAKER([LEFT](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3518954/))
>  PETE DOCTER ([UP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_(2009_film)))

Which gives -

> [image]

Next -

> We see the Red bar and we also need to replace a letter in the right picture. So, if we use the Red Bar as word separator and take the left or right letter based on its position, we get -
>  [image]

So, the words we get are -

> [image]

So, looking at the words, it makes sense to declare -

> [image]
>  Mr. DICK MAAS as the Winner!

But...

> We haven't used one clue i.e. 2012 in the title. So, may be OP want's us to find a Director with a movie which has "Center" in its title and have released in the year 2012. So we get -
>  [image]
>  Joseph Lawson [(Nazis at the center of the Earth)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2130142/)

Or

> Since the winner was "DOWN", we have to find a movie with Down in the Title and released in 2012.
>  [image]
>  Daniel Barnz ([Wont Back Down](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1870529/))

Comment: For the director at the top you've switched his first/last names throughout for some reason.

Comment: lol @JaapScherphuis I got that name from reverse image search tbh :D

Comment: "A letter has been replaced with an X"... so I thought it was the same letter.

Comment: Nice approach, but not the correct one. You're correct regarding the movies but the interpretation is just like @ACB says. All X's stand for the same letter.